# How to make a matrix of duplicate word in text data

Tags: python, matrix, nlp, duplicates

I want to read some text file and Find out how many times each word is repeated per line?
this is my text file

1. خواب خودرو چگونه محاسبه می گردد؟ برای دریافت آن چه باید كرد؟
2. مهلت زمانی تامین قطعه پس از درخواست مشتری چند روز است؟
3. آیا در مراجعه مجدد برای ایرادی كه پس از تعمیرات رفع نشده است باید هزینه ای پرداخت گردد؟ چرا؟
4. چرا توزیع قطعات در نمایندگی ها مختلف شهر متفاوت است؟

and make a output like this

```
line#       word#1    word#2    word#3 ......
  1            2        0          1 
  2            0        0          2
  .
  .
  .
```

i want to create a function to do this , i can't use countvectorizer function for persian language

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude tnx, i made a edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

```
line_counter = 1
with open("text.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    lines = opened_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        repeated_elem = {}
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word in repeated_elem:
                repeated_elem[word] += 1
                continue
            repeated_elem[word] = 1
        print("{line}. line. Words: {words}".format(line=line_counter, words=repeated_elem))
        line_counter += 1
```

**Content of my text file:**

```
hello hi aloha hello bye
one two three four five two
yes no yes no yes no yes
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
1. line. Words: {'hello': 2, 'hi': 1, 'aloha': 1, 'bye': 1}
2. line. Words: {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 1, 'four': 1, 'five': 1}
3. line. Words: {'yes': 4, 'no': 3}
```